# Issue with .addClass method of tinymce.dom.DOMUtils class in tinymce 4.3.12

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to migrate from **tinymce version 4.1.9** to latest **[tinymce version 4.3.12](https://www.tinymce.com/download/)**. I have a custom button which fires an event and simultaneously toggle (change the image of the button). It works fine with earlier versions of tinymce (all versions of 3.x and 4.1.2) but now giving an error message in tinymce 4.3.12.

Error message is: `Uncaught TypeError: self.addClass is not a function` in chrome debug console.

I have checked the latest [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce.dom.domutils/#addclass) and which clearly shows `.addClass` is part of the library ([tinymce.dom.DOMUtils](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce.dom.domutils/#addclass) class).

See below part of the code I am using:

```
 tinymce.init({
       setup: function (ed) {
                    ed.addButton('autosave', {
                    image:  '/images/autosave_disk_off.png',
                    cmd: 'autosave',
                    selectable: true,
                    onClick: toggleAutoSave,
                    onPostRender: function() {
                      var self = this;
                      self.addClass('classAutosave');
                      ed.on('autosaveStateChanged', function(e) {
                      self.active(e.state);
                         });
                    }});
                  }
              });
```

I want to add a class to current element so that image switching can be done.

Can someone help to understand the reason why this code is not working in tinymce 4.3.12?

Is there alternate way to add class in onPostRender?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I sort of figured out the reason, what I have done is that compared the code of `tinymce.js` version 3.1.10 and `tinymce.js` version 3.2.0. I chose 3.1.10 because this is the last version in which my `addClass()` works. This is breaking in and after from 3.2.0.
While comparing, I found a lot of code changes has been done for `addClass()` and `removeClass()` API's. I also found that internally tinymce is using `self.classes.add('classAutosave')` to add new class. So I tried the same way in my plug-in and it works. So far, I haven't found any documentation mentioning this change. I am still checking in tinymce forums probably I will open a ticket with tinymce dev. Will update answer if any new info arrives.

**Observation:**

Use  `self.classes.add('classAutosave')` instead of `self.addclass('classAutosave')`for adding new class with [**tinymce 3.20**](https://www.tinymce.com/download/older-releases/) -> [**tinymce 4.3.12**](https://www.tinymce.com/download/).

Comment: Upgrading from 4.1.7 to 4.7.13 I also just fixed this by replacing `.addClass()` with `.classes.add()`.